# Different behavior of Text and Labeled controls in combination with css

Tags: css, javafx, resize, label, controls

I am working on a Javafx application and I tried to add some Labels, Buttons and Texts, which resizes when the user resizing the Scene. All Nodes are inside a VBox, which itself is inside a StackPane.

**My test application:**

```
public class Test extends Application 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) 
    {           
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label l = new Label("Label");
        Text t = new Text("Text");
        t.getStyleClass().add("test");
        Button b = new Button("Button");
        pane.heightProperty().addListener(listener ->
        {
            double h = pane.getHeight()/5;          
            l.setFont(Font.font(l.getFont().getFamily(), h));
            t.setFont(Font.font(t.getFont().getFamily(), h));
            b.setFont(Font.font(b.getFont().getFamily(), h));
        });
        
        box.getChildren().addAll(l, t, b);
        pane.getChildren().add(box);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(Path.of("test.css").toUri().toString());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If I resize the Stage it works as expected. But unfortunately only with pure Java code.
Because after adding my css file, the Labeled controls behave different. While the Text elements continue to change in size, the Labels and Buttons does not change their size anymore.

**My css file, which does not work:**

```
.label
{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
   -fx-font-family: impact;
}

.test
{
   -fx-fill: red;
   -fx-font-family: impact;
   -fx-font-size: 2em;
}

.button
{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
   -fx-font-size: 2em;
}
```

I asked myself what I did wrong and have tested different css states. I found out, when I omit font values in css it works, otherwise it does not. Therewhile it does not matter which font value occurs, only one font value is required to miss the behavior.

**My css file, which works:**

```
.label
{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
   //-fx-font-family: impact;
}

.test
{
   -fx-fill: red;
   -fx-font-family: impact;
   -fx-font-size: 2em;
}

.button
{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
   //-fx-font-size: 2em;
}
```

### 1. Question: -has changed, see below-

Do I missunderstand something about css and Javafx, or did I something wrong in my css file or is there a bug?

### 2. Question: -solved-

Have I to put the font values with java code or is there an other way to add the font?

Thank You for helping!

---

### Update

As recommended I have studying the follow guide:
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

The JavaFX CSS implementation applies the following order of precedence:

> The implementation allows designers to style an application by using style sheets to override property values set from code. For example, a call to rectangle.setFill(Color.YELLOW) can be overridden by an inline‑style or a style from an author stylesheet. This has implications for the cascade; particularly, when does a style from a style sheet override a value set from code? The JavaFX CSS implementation applies the following order of precedence: a style from a user agent style sheet has lower priority than a value set from code, which has lower priority than a Scene or Parent style sheet. Inline styles have highest precedence. Style sheets from a Parent instance are considered to be more specific than those styles from Scene style sheets.

In my case this means, I will use the inline style to make it proper.

### thus the 2. Question is solved

But, because of **Parent style sheet > value set from code**, it also means, all Nodes are not allowed to change theire size, even the Text Node.

### Therefore I changed my 1. Question to:

[Why does the JavaFX CSS order of precedence differ between Text and Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213860/why-does-the-javafx-css-order-of-precedence-differ-between-text-and-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

It's not a bug, it's a conflict of priorities. `.setFont()` has a lower priority than that `CSS`. Just replace `.setFont()` to `.setStyle()` and sample will work as you planned:

```
l.setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + h + ";");
t.setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + h + ";");
b.setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + h + ";");
```

**Question 2:**

Try to keep all about styles in `CSS`. It's the best practice.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your solution works as so far that I can set the font in css. But why is the priority of the Text different to the priority of the Labeled controls? The distinction makes no sense to me. Do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: `Button` and `Label` are `Control`s, and `Text` is a `Shape`. They have different `CSS` properties. I don't know which specific property is responsible for this effect, but I think that the exact answer can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You solved my 2. question and caused me to change my 1. question.